# Cleaning up text in an inconsistent format in Python

Tags: python-3.x, text, nlp, named-entity-recognition

I'm trying to learn textual analysis in Python by analyzing Congressional testimony transcripts. I've been able to extract the text from the PDF transcripts, but the text is very dirty. I'm not sure how to clean it up. I'm trying to convert this:

```
`["HOUSE COMMITTEE ON BANKING, FINANCE AND URBAN AFFAIRSHENRY S. REUSS, Wisconsin, ChairmanTHOMAS'L. 
ASHLEY, OhioWILLIAM S. MOORHEAD, PennsylvaniaFERNAND J. ST GERMAIN, Rhode Island", "HENRY B. 
GONZALEZ, TexasPAUL NELSON, Clerk and Staff DirectorMICHAEL P. FLAHERTY, General CounselMERCER L. 
JACKSON, Minority Staff Director(H)']`
```

to a list of names, states, and title (ex: "Chairman"), like this:

```
`[["HENRY S. REUSS", "Wisconsin", "Chairman"],
["THOMAS'L. ASHLEY", "Ohio"],
["WILLIAM S. MOORHEAD", "Pennsylvania"],
["FERNAND J. ST GERMAIN", "Rhode Island"], 
["HENRY B. GONZALEZ", "Texas"], 
["PAUL NELSON", "Clerk and Staff Director"],
["MICHAEL P. FLAHERTY", "General Counsel"],
["MERCER L. JACKSON", "Minority Staff Director(H)"]]`
```

Note that some individuals have a state and title associated with their name, while some have just a state or title associated with their name. Is this type of conversion doable? Any recommendations on how to approach this? Any help will be greatly appreciated. Cheers!
-Mike

Comment: Could you please share a sample PDF or a link from where this information is sourced.  One could investigate the issue better.

Comment: @SidharthMacherla I'd be happy to share the file, but I don't see an option to upload a file unfortunately. Am I missing something?

Comment: @SidharthMacherla Here is a link to a sample document. I'm trying to extract the names on the second page. https://fraser.stlouisfed.org/title/monetary-policy-oversight-672/conduct-monetary-policy-pursuant-full-employment-balanced-growth-act-1978-pl-95-523-22392